# How to use the output of a tiddlywiki widget itself as a value for another wikitext expression?

Tags: tiddlywiki, wikitext, tiddlywiki5

Currently I'm trying to create a macro. The macro will be used within a `$list` widget which will cycle through a collection of tiddlers (chosen as per certain filter criteria which themselves aren't relevant here).

Within the above `$list` widget, for each tiddler, the macro will go through all of the fields of the tiddler that have a certain prefix (which is "link_"). These fields contain as their value internet URLs.

Not only do I wish to display these URLs (for each tiddler) as a list, I wish them to act as hyperlinks to said URLs.

Now so far the below macro has worked for the moment:

```
\define myMacro(prefix:"")
<$list filter="[fields[]prefix[$prefix$]sort[title]]" variable="fieldName">

<$transclude field=<<fieldName>>/>

</$list>
\end
```

What the above does is simply print the value (the URL) of that field while making sure it also acts as a hyperlink to that particular URL.

BUT

I wish to improve this further. Instead of the text of those links being the link itself, I want it to be a custom text.

For eg:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming

vs.

[Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming) (hyperlink to the same page but with custom hyperlink text)

But doing the above is seemingly impossible with the above `$transclude` method unless there is a way of using the output of a widget itself as a value.

I've already checked something direct like:

```
[[Custom link name|<$transclude field=<<fieldName>>/>]]
```

or

```
<a href=<$transclude field=<<fieldName>>/> >Custom link name</a>
```

Doesn't work.

I've tried other methods too but they don't work. How do they not work?

Let's say there is a variable in that particular tiddler called `list_1` and it's value is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming`. I wish to use the `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming` as the `href` value of an `<a>` tag.

But with all the methods I've tried, at best I can access the value `list_1` itself via `<<fieldName>>`.

Only the **$transclude** method itself allows me to use the value of `list_1` itself (ie `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming`), but it doesn't allow you AFAIK to use it as a value in an another wikitext expression.

So how do I achieve my aforementioned objective? Is there a way to use the output of a widget itself as a value for another wikitext expression or is there some other way to accomplish my objective?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

not sure I understand your goal but this is definately wrong:

```
<a href=<$transclude field=<<fieldName>>/> >Custom link name</a>
```

you should use the <$link widget to create links and a filter for attribute values

```
<$link to={{{[[title]get<fieldName>]}}}>Custom link name</$link>
```

or

```
<$link to={{{[<variableWithTitle>get<fieldName>]}}}>Custom link name</$link>
```

Edit: added title to filter

Comment: Your solution `<$link to={{{[get<fieldName>]}}}>Custom link name</$link>` did not work. Pointed to a non-existent tiddler with the same title as the value of  `{{{[get<fieldName>]}}}`.

Although I tried  `{{{[get<fieldName>]}}}` in :
`<a href={{{[get<fieldName>]}}} target="blank_"><<fieldName>></a>`

This worked. So thanks anyways I guess.

Comment: @KeyboardPenman fixed the filter, sory for the late respond